# Overload handling of std::endl?

Tags: c++, overloading, iostream, manipulators, endl

I want to define a class `MyStream` so that:

```
MyStream myStream;
myStream << 1 << 2 << 3 << std::endl << 5 << 6 << std::endl << 7 << 8 << std::endl;
```

gives output

```
[blah]123
[blah]56
[blah]78
```

Basically, I want a "[blah]" inserted at the front, then inserted after every *non terminating* `std::endl`?

The difficulty here is NOT the logic management, but detecting and overloading the handling of `std::endl`. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Thanks!

EDIT: I don't need advice on logic management. I need to know how to detect/overload printing of `std::endl`.

Comment: You just need to override the stream buffer with a version that has it own unique version of sync()

Answer (score 35, accepted):

What you need to do is write your own stream buffer: When the stream buffer is flushed you output you prefix characters and the content of the stream.

The following works because `std::endl` causes the following.

1. Add `'\n'` to the stream.
2. Calls `flush()` on the stream
3. This calls `pubsync()` on the stream buffer.

   1. This calls the virtual method `sync()`
   2. Override this virtual method to do the work you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class MyStream: public std::ostream
{
    // Write a stream buffer that prefixes each line with Plop
    class MyStreamBuf: public std::stringbuf
    {
        std::ostream&   output;
        public:
            MyStreamBuf(std::ostream& str)
                :output(str)
            {}
            ~MyStreamBuf() {
                if (pbase() != pptr()) {
                    putOutput();
                }
            }
   
        // When we sync the stream with the output. 
        // 1) Output Plop then the buffer
        // 2) Reset the buffer
        // 3) flush the actual output stream we are using.
        virtual int sync() {
            putOutput();
            return 0;
        }
        void putOutput() {
            // Called by destructor.
            // destructor can not call virtual methods.
            output << "[blah]" << str();
            str("");
            output.flush();
        }
    };

    // My Stream just uses a version of my special buffer
    MyStreamBuf buffer;
    public:
        MyStream(std::ostream& str)
            :std::ostream(&buffer)
            ,buffer(str)
        {
        }
};


int main()
{
    MyStream myStream(std::cout);
    myStream << 1 << 2 << 3 << std::endl << 5 << 6 << std::endl << 7 << 8 << std::endl;
}
```

```
> ./a.out
[blah]123 
[blah]56 
[blah]78
>
```

Comment: -1: You copied my advice without giving credit, instead leaving criticism (huh?), and furthermore only went halfway. You didn't override `overflow`, so your code fails if `putc('\n')` results in overflow before `sync` gets called.

Comment: Ohhh, overflow never happens in a `stringbuf`. Sorry… it's sunrise here… sleepy.

Comment: Yeah… if you apply a token edit I'll reverse that vote… tomorrow

Comment: @potatoswatter: That's a bit egotistical to think I copied you. No copying involved. You came up with a description of possibilities. I came up with a solution. And we did it completely independently. Guss what: I have done this kind of thing before :-)

Comment: I would like a flush to be triggered by a read on std::cin or end of program. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: @Macbeth'sEnigma: That is already done. If you read from std::cin the std::cout is automatically flushed first. When an application exists all buffers will be flushed.

Comment: `myStream << "This does not print.";` whereas `std::cout << "This does print.";` I have to force it with `myStream << "This will print now" << std:flush;` I am hoping to replicate the cout behavior of triggering at end or std::cin.

Comment: From Joseuutis The C++ Standard Library, this works: `std::cin.tie(&myStream);` Is there a way to incorporate that in the MyStream class? I am still trying to get end of program to trigger a flush.

Comment: FWIW, I put this in the form of an SO question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532460/can-a-custom-stream-buffer-automatically-flush-at-program-exit-and-when-requesti

Comment: Question, does one need to call `flush` from the destructor of `MyStream`, or does `std::ostream` does it for you? It is not clear from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/%7Ebasic_ostream

Comment: @alfC: Well spotted. Added a destructor (to the buffer).

Comment: Curious, I though you would add a `[virtual?] ~MyStream(){flush();}`. Wouldn't that be simpler? and equivalent?

Comment: Any arguments against making `MyStream` inherit privately from `std::stringbuf` as well so you don't have that extra class, while leaving the stream class almost empty?

Answer (score 18):

Your overloaded operators of the `MyStream` class have to set a previous-printed-token-was-endl flag.

Then, if the next object is printed, the `[blah]` can be inserted in front of it.

`std::endl` is a function taking and returning a reference to `std::ostream`. To detect it was shifted into your stream, you have to overload the `operator<<` between your type and such a function:

```
MyStream& operator<<( std::ostream&(*f)(std::ostream&) )
{
    std::cout << f;

    if( f == std::endl )
    {
        _lastTokenWasEndl = true;
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not detect just std::endl - it detects any manipulator that has no parameters. But I guess in the <<() operator you could compare f with std::endl, and do special processing if they are the same thing.

Comment: In the middle of editing the post I wasn't sure if the comparison to endl would work, but I tested it and it does :-)

Comment: This won't work for the same reason as you can never derive from `ostream`: formatting inserters are defined to return an `ostream&`. Even if you override all the default ones, there are still user-defined `ostream &operator<<( ostream &, my_type const & )`'s floating around. Then `my_stream << my_type(5) << endl;` calls `operator<<( ostream&, manipulator )`, not `operator<<( MyStream&, manipulator )`.

Comment: The code as it stands turns off all the other manipulators - you need to call them in the "else" logic: f( *this );

Comment: This should work, except that GCC complains "assuming cast to type 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)' from overloaded function" on the comparison of `f` to `std::endl`. @Neil: This doesn't "turn off" any manipulators; they are passed to `std::cout` and applied there.

Comment: @Gabriel, you should just do as GCC suggests: cast `if (f == (std::basic_ostream<char>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>&)) &std::endl) { ... }`.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed with Neil on principle.

You want to change the behavior of the buffer, because that is the only way to extend iostreams. `endl` does this:

```
flush(__os.put(__os.widen('\n')));
```

`widen` returns a single character, so you can't put your string in there. `put` calls `putc` which is not a virtual function and only occasionally hooks to `overflow`. You can intercept at `flush`, which calls the buffer's `sync`. You would need to intercept and change all newline characters as they are `overflow`ed or manually `sync`ed and convert them to your string.

Designing an override buffer class is troublesome because `basic_streambuf` expects direct access to its buffer memory. This prevents you from easily passing I/O requests to a preexisting `basic_streambuf`. You need to go out on a limb and suppose you know the stream buffer class, and derive from it. (`cin` and `cout` are not guaranteed to use `basic_filebuf`, far as I can tell.) Then, just add `virtual overflow` and `sync`. (See §27.5.2.4.5/3 and 27.5.2.4.2/7.) Performing the substitution may require additional space so be careful to allocate that ahead of time.

### - OR -

Just declare a new `endl` in your own namespace, or better, a manipulator which isn't called `endl` at all!

Comment: You are over complicating things. Use the std::stringbuf class to do the buffering.

Comment: @Martin: He asked how to change the behavior of `ostream`. I can only assume he wants to work with files. Anyway, even if you use `stringbuf`, you're still in the same situation of deriving, overloading, and substituting: it doesn't simplify anything. Forgetting the whole streams mess and performing search-and-replace on the result of `mystringstream.str()`, on the other hand, would be very reasonable!

Comment: @Patatoswatter: Please read my solution. I think 30 lines (including comments) is relatively trivial.

Comment: @Martin: yes, it's simple, but on the scale of complexity it's somewhere between what I thought and "use the std::stringbuf class".

Answer (score 2):

I use function pointers.  It sounds terrifying to people who aren't used to C, but it's a lot more efficient in most cases.  Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo& operator<<(const char* str) { std::cout << str; return *this; }
    // If your compiler allows it, you can omit the "fun" from *fun below.  It'll make it an anonymous parameter, though...
    Foo& operator<<(std::ostream& (*fun)(std::ostream&)) { std::cout << std::endl; }
} foo;

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    foo << "This is a test!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you really want to you can check for the address of endl to confirm that you aren't getting some OTHER void/void function, but I don't think it's worth it in most cases.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of attempting to modify the behavior of `std::endl`, you should probably create a filtering streambuf to do the job. James Kanze has an [example](http://kanze.james.neuf.fr/articles/fltrsbf1.html) showing how to insert a timestamp at the beginning of each output line. It should require only minor modification to change that to whatever prefix you want on each line.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question, and I thought that Potatoswatter's second answer had merit: "Just declare a new endl in your own namespace, or better, a manipulator which isn't called endl at all!"

So I found out how to write a custom manipulator which is not hard at all:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

class log_t : public std::ostringstream
{
    public:
};


std::ostream& custom_endl(std::ostream& out)
{
    log_t *log = dynamic_cast<log_t*>(&out);
    if (log)
    {
        std::cout << "custom endl succeeded.\n";
    }
    out << std::endl;
    return out;
}

std::ostream& custom_flush(std::ostream& out)
{
    log_t *log = dynamic_cast<log_t*>(&out);
    if (log)
    {
        std::cout << "custom flush succeeded.\n";
    }
    out << std::flush;
    return out;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    log_t log;

    log << "custom endl test" << custom_endl;
    log << "custom flush test" << custom_flush;

    std::cout << "Contents of log:\n" << log.str() << std::endl;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
custom endl succeeded.
custom flush succeeded.
Contents of log:
custom endl test
custom flush test
```

Here I've created two custom manipulators, one that handles `endl` and one that handles `flush`. You can add whatever processing you want to these two functions, since you have a pointer to the `log_t` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change `std::endl` - as it's name suggests it is a part of the C++ Standard Library  and its behaviour is fixed. You need to change the behaviour of the stream itself, when it receives an end of line . Personally, I would not have thought this worth the effort, but if you want to venture into this area I strongly recommend reading the book [Standard C++ IOStreams & Locales](http://www.angelikalanger.com/iostreams.html).

Comment: Good book. But not one I recommend of beginners. But if you want to learn how to manipulate the stream classes it is a must read.

Comment: @Martin I wouldn't recommend it to beginners either, but then writing specialised streams is not a task for beginners.

Comment: Agreed: <-----15 Char ------>              :-)