# Is it possible to override std::endl?

Tags: c++

I am creating a wrapper class around `std::ofstream`. I have override all the `std::ofstream` methods. Now, I need to override the `std::endl` method to use the wrapper class instead of `basic_ostream`.

Is it possible to override `std::endl` method? Can anyone give me an example?

Comment: There's no class to override it in.  `std::endl` is a free function.

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212776/overload-handling-of-stdendl

Comment: `std::ofstream` has hardly any virtual functions so there is not a lot to override. (Deriving from `std::ofstream` is not usually a good way to implement <iostream> extending functionality.) Why doesn't `std::endl` work with your new class is? If you want to do something different, why not just write a new function. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

First: You are never allowed to overload functions in the `::std` namespace. In fact, you are **only** allowed to specialize existing templates in the `::std` namespace and that only with restrictions.

You can however deal with the `endl` situation by reading what it actually does in C++11 27.7.3.8/1:

> Effects: Calls os.put(os.widen(’\n’)), then os.flush().

Therefore, you need to override nothing, just provide the correct member functions to deal with this sequence of `put`, `widen` and `flush`.

Comment: None of `put`, `widen` or `flush` are virtual in `std::basic_ostream` or its bases and as `endl` is templated on the character type and not the stream type, providing versions of these functions in a class derived from `std::ostream` is pointless.

Comment: I was assuming the OP was wrapping `ofstream` and inheriting `streambuf`, since he stated to have successfully "overridden" the `ofstream` methods.

Answer (score 1):

You could override `operator<<` for the type of `std::endl`, then check inside the overload whether you were passed std::endl. However: I don't think what you are doing is smart, although without really knowing what you want to achieve, it's hard to suggest a better approach. I'd say you should describe what your goal is instead of asking how to achieve a certain (flawed) solution.