# Can a custom stream buffer automatically flush at program exit and when requesting input?

Tags: c++, iostream

[Loki Astari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14065/loki-astari) provides [this custom steam buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2212940/1883451). How can I change the class to automatically flush when reading from cin::cin or when the application exists? For example:

```
int main ()
{
    MyStream myStream(std::cout);
    myStream << "This does not print.";
}
```

and

```
int main()
{
    MyStream myStream(std::cout);
    myStream << "This does not print.";
    std::cin.get();
}
```

whereas

```
std::cout << "This does print.";
```

and

```
std::cout << "This does print.";
std::cin.get();
```

If I force it

```
myStream << "This will now print." << std::flush;
```

However, I am hoping to replicate the cout behavior of triggering at program exit or std::cin automatically.

This works (thanks to Josuttis's "The C++ Standard Library"):

```
    MyStream myStream(std::cout);
    std::cin.tie(&myStream);
    myStream << "This will now print.";
    std::cin.get();
```

because `std::cint.tie(&std::cout)` is a predefined connection.

**Question #1**: Can I modify the MyStream class to tie it to the cin stream so that I do not have to issue a `std::cin.tie(&myStream)` every time I create an instance?

**Question #2**: How can the MyStream class be modified so that the buffer will be automatically flushed at program exit?

Comment: Call `cin.tie(this)` in your stream's constructor. Bear in mind that this will destroy the tie `cin` has with `cout`. For doing stuff at program's exit, use a static object with a destructor.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks. Put it in the form of an answer and I'll mark it answered. :) Interestingly, cin.get() still flushes cout & MyStream. If I `myStream << "print"; cin.get(); cout << "print with cout"; cin.get()` both flush properly. But if I `myStream << "Print"; cout << "print with cout ";` console shows `print with cout Print`. cout must be destroyed before myStream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Constructors are designed to do things at object creation time, so it would be appropriate to establish the tie in the constructor of `MyStream`: `std::cin.tie(this);`. This will probably break any tie that exists between `cin` and `cout`, and.or between `cin` abd another instance of your stream class.
2. For doing things at program exit, C++ has destructors of objects with static storage duration.